# Join two tables with less time

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have two tables `TableProject` and `TableFlag`; I want to join them together with some conditions.
So first I get the list from the first table then check the second table to find proper value in a for  loop.

Although it works but it is pretty slow, it takes about 10 seconds.

```
// Step 1 get the list from the first table
var temp = Task.FromResult(await myDatabase.TableProject.
                Select(p => new ProjectDto
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Type = p.Type,
                    Status = p.Status
                })
                .Where(x => x.Type != 999)
                .Orderby(y => y.Name).ToListAsync());
var list = temp.Result;

// Step 2 check the second table to find right values in a for loop.
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if(list[i].Type.HasValue)
    {
         list[i].ProjectType = (from f in myDatabase.TableFlag
                            where f.FlagName == "PROJECT TYPE" && f.FlagId == list[i].Type
                            select f.FlagValue).FirstOrDefaut();
    }
    if(list[i].Type.HasValue)
    {
         list[i].Status = (from f in myDatabase.TableFlag
                            where f.FlagName == "PROJECT STATUS" && f.FlagId == list[i].Status
                            select f.FlagValue).FirstOrDefaut();
    }
}       
return Json(list);
```

If you look at step 2, it takes o(n^2) time.

**Update:**

Sql query(T-SQL) is welcomed. I can use the stored procedure.

Comment: Put the C# code to one side. Let's say you had to write this **just using SQL**. What would that query look like?

Comment: @mjwills, good point. Actually I have no idea how to write SQL query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 'let' clauses, they will be translated into joins or subqueries in the database. This will lower the amount of database roundtrips and the query will run much faster.

```
var query =
  from project in myDatabase.TableProject
  where project.Type != 999
  order by project.Name
  let statusFlag = myDatabase.TableFlag
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.FlagName == "PROJECT STATUS" && f.FlagId == project.Status)
  let typeFlag = myDatabase.TableFlag
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.FlagName == "PROJECT TYPE" && f.FlagId == project.Type)
  select new ProjectDto {
    Id = project.Id,
    Name = project.Name,
    Type = project.Type,
    Status = statusFlag?.FlagValue,
    ProjectType = typeFlag?.FlagValue
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can crerate a materialized view on the DB by joining your two tables and than only get the results of the view in your app. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest if you have SQL Server or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm if you have ORACLE DB. The materialized view is much faster than a normal view or only a join.

Comment: Well, thanks for your input. But I don't want to create a view because I don't have the permission.